# Do I need to clean up the char* passed to NewStringUTF?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I think yes, but the top 12 examples I found all do something not illustrative like

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JCALL Java_com_foo_dumbImpl(JNIEnv* env, jobject thisObj)
{
  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "constant string"); 
}
```

so for posterity I will ask: this is bad, yes?

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JCALL Java_com_foo_dumbImpl(JNIEnv* env, jobject thisObj)
{
  char *leak = malloc(1024);
  leak[0] = '\0';
  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, leak); 
}
```

...and should be:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JCALL Java_com_foo_dumbImpl(JNIEnv* env, jobject thisObj)
{
  char *emptystring = NULL;
  jstring r = NULL;
  emptystring = malloc(1024);
  emptystring[0] = '\0';
  r = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, emptystring); 
  free(emptystring);
  emptystring = NULL;
  return  r;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. (Just so this doesn't look unanswered.)

Answer (score 3):

It's good to be concerned about memory leaks, however, in this case, there is no leak (original example).  "constant string" is a literal string; it is not allocated from the heap.

So, no, you do not need to clean up the char * passed (original example).

Your edited examples are better for illustrating your point.  In the edited example, yes, you need to clean up the passed string.