# pointer error with c++ and ndk

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

im attempting to build c++ code with ndk-build but i keep getting this error `base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEnv <aka _JNIEnv>'`

i have tried every solution on the first 2 pages of google with no luck, the ndk just isnt being good to me.

nativemain.h

```
#ifndef NATIVEMAIN_H
#define NATIVEMAIN_H

#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

extern "C"
{

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_ndktest3_MyRenderer_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz );
}

#endif
```

nativemain.cpp

```
#include <nativemain.h>


JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_ndktest3_MyRenderer_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
    return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from JNI !");
}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := nativemain
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := nativemain.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Posible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764948/error-base-operand-of-has-non-pointer-type-jnienv

Comment: no need to backdoor moderate. I already tryed that solution as you can see if you would have look at the code

Comment: Apologies for not paying attention and sorry it didn't help.

Comment: no worries this ndk is just stressing me

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your syntax slightly

I believe the error is the miss-use of the '->' operator

"

```
{
    return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from JNI !");
}
```

try casting env as a pointer like so

```
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, str);
}
```

where str is a predefined string such as your hello message.

check this post as a cross reference: [Do I need to clean up the char* passed to NewStringUTF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827549/do-i-need-to-clean-up-the-char-passed-to-newstringutf)

Comment: That's actually dereferencing rather than casting.  `env` is a pointer to a pointer to a struct, while the `->` operator expects a pointer to a struct, so we have to dereference the outer pointer before using `->` on the remaining pointer to a struct.